# Vue js 2 Persist a component's data *privately*

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex, persist

I currently have a Vue.js 2 SPA using Vuex for inter-component communication and Vuex-persisted state to persist my shared state.

However, I want to persist a component's *local* *private* data.

I tried the package vue-persist and it persists the component data fine, however, the variables are not namespaced and therefore shared between *all* component instances.  I want to persist each component's data separately.

Does anyone know how I can achieve these 2 things in my Vue.js 2.x app?

1) Persistence of my local data (so it survives a browser refresh).
2) The persisted data is *not* shared with other components (perhaps name-spaced for each component instance?).

Thanks!

Comment: I use this approach and save to sessionStore:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43027499/vuex-state-on-page-refresh

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with [`vue-persist`](https://github.com/egoist/vue-persist), but it looks like you can pass a store name as the second argument to `$persist`. Choose a unique store name for the component instance (this will vary depending on the component).

e.g.

```js
created() {
  this.$persist(['foo'], 'my-comp:' + this.id);
}
```

Comment: That works perfectly, ignore my previous dumb attempts to get it working - I was just passing my unique id in a ridiculous way.  I thank you.