# Vuex state not preserved after page redirect

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

In a Vue.js I have this method to login users, set the values int vuex store and then redirect to home page:

```
   login: function () {
            axios.post( this.BASE_URL + "/login", {
            username: this.username,
            password: this.password,
          }).then( (res) => { 
                this.$store.commit('setIsAuthenticated', true);
                this.$store.commit('setToken', res.data.token);
                this.$store.commit('setPhoto', res.data.photo);
                this.$store.commit('setUsername', res.data.username);
                window.location.href = '/home'; //<-The problem     
          }
```

Example mutations:

```
setToken: function (state, token) {
    state.token = token;
    },
setUsername: function (state, username) {
    state.username = username;
},
```

At `App.vue` (the root component), I just get values from the store as computed values:

```
  computed: {
    isAuthenticated () {
    return this.$store.state.isAuthenticated;
    },

    token () {
        return this.$store.state.token; 
    } ,
```

When I comment out `window.location.href = '/home';` I see in Vue.js console that the login is successful and values are set in the store, However as soon as the page is redirected to `/home` all store values are emptied.
I'm wondering why this happens and how to fix it?

UPDATE:
I'm using vue-router in a `routes.js` like this:

```
import webLogin from './components/webLogin.vue';
import showAll from './components/showAll.vue';

export default [ 
  {path:'/', component: showAll },
  {path:'/add', component: addJoke  }  ,
  {path: '/login', component: webLogin},  
]
```

Comment: Do you use Vue router?

Comment: Yes I do use vue router.

Comment: `window.location.href` loads an entirely new page. If you need the data to be available across page requests, you'll need to persist it somewhere. I'd go with `localStorage` for now

Comment: Try https://github.com/robinvdvleuten/vuex-persistedstate or https://github.com/crossjs/vuex-localstorage

Comment: This answer might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43027499/vuex-state-on-page-refresh/60900161

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Vuex state is kept in memory. If you redirect with `window.location.href` this will trigger a full page load, which will purge your current state. You have to use Vue router to do your navigation https://router.vuejs.org/en/

For example if your route name is `Home` you can redirect like this:

```
this.$router.push({ name: 'Home' });
```

Comment: Would you please elaborate how to redirect using vue router in my code's  context?

Comment: I edited my answer, not sure how you set up your routes though.

Comment: I added `this.$router.push({ path: '/home' });` and now it works like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

***Use Vuejs to navigate between the pages, don't do it manually***

Unless you navigate from one page to another using Vuejs routes, state will not be preserved. Consider these two scenarios

1. After setting the state in the store from one page. You enter the URL for another page directly in to the browser window and hit enter. Check the state in the store. It will not be preserved and will be reset to default values.
2. After setting the state in the store from one page. You navigate to the another page using Vuejs route

In Nuxtjs

```
<nuxt-link to="discussion/1">Go to Discussion</nuxt-link>
```

In Vuejs

```
<router-link to="discussion/1">Go to Discussion</router-link>
```

Check the state in the store. It will be preserved in the store.

Comment: its not working after login i do this this.$store.authstore.commit("authenticate", sesion); and then this.$router.push({ name: "home" }); but in "home" when i try to access console.log(this.$store.authstore.getters.username); is empty