# Vuex Store value updates not reflected

Tags: vue.js

I am using store variable and updating it but when I refresh the page, the data gets empty

I have defined a variable and tried to use it as "this.state.userInfo"

```
export default new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        status: '',
        token: localStorage.getItem('token') || '',
        userInfo: {}
    },
    actions: {
        login () {
            this.state.userInfo = "John"
        },
        autoLogin () {
            const userInfo = this.state.userInfo
        }
  }
})
```

this.state.userInfo should be updated but it is reflecting me an empty value when I refresh the page.

Comment: userInfo should be string. Hence update userInfo: {} => userInfo: ''

Comment: @Riddhi, thanks for replying but this isn't working

Comment: Check the value in console => login () {
            this.state.userInfo = "John";console.log(this.state.userInfo)
        },

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vuex state on page refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43027499/vuex-state-on-page-refresh)