# Redirected to login after refreshing page in nuxtjs and laravel sanctum

Tags: laravel, authentication, nuxt.js, laravel-sanctum, nuxt-auth

i have a problem with Nuxt SSR mode in production
auth with Laravel sanctum

login success but when refresh any page, redirecting to login page and logout !!!

Comment: You might want to check middleware or layout of a page to see if there is a logic to redirect.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vuex state on page refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43027499/vuex-state-on-page-refresh)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by adding the following code:

`headers: { Referer: baseURL, }`

in auth strategy > endpoints > user

Comment: Hello. I'm trying to solve the same issue. Can you be more explicte where should I put this code? (I'm new to Nuxt, actually I have done the laravel dev and now helping the frontend team)