# How to keep updated array stay same even if page is refreshed in Vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

**HelloWorld.vue**

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <b>Vuejs dynamic routing</b>
    <div v-for="item in items" :key="item.id">
      <b>{{ item.id }}.</b> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <router-link :to="{ name: 'UserWithID', params: { id: item.id, item } }">
        {{ item.val }}{{ item.kk }}
      </router-link>
    </div>
    <br /><br /><br />
  </div>
</template>
 
<script>
import { data } from "../data";
export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",
  data() {
    return {
      items: data,
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

**User.vue**

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <form>
      <label>Val:</label><br />
      <input type="text" id="val" name="val" v-model="val" /><br />
      <label>kk:</label><br />
      <input type="text" id="kk" name="kk" v-model="kk" /><br /><br />
      <button @click="updateData">submit</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { data } from "../data";
export default {
  name: "User",
  props: {
    item: {
      required: true,
      type: Object,
    },
  },
  data: function () {
    return {
      val: this.item.val,
      kk: this.item.kk,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    updateData() {
      const id = this.$route.params.id;
      let newData = data.find((value) => value.id === id);
      newData.kk = this.kk;
      newData.val = this.val;
      this.$router.push({ path: "/" });
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

**main.js**

```html
import Vue from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import VueRouter from "vue-router";
import HelloWorld from "./components/HelloWorld.vue";
import User from "./components/User.vue";

Vue.use(VueRouter);

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    { path: "/", name: "User", component: HelloWorld, props:true },
    { path: "/User/:id", name: "UserWithID", component: User, props:true }
  ]
});

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  router,
  render: (h) => h(App)
}).$mount("#app");
```

This is my complete working code:- https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-dhawan-3id77?file=/src/main.js

If you please go through my code once above, initially I have some router-link and onclick of router-link, I am able to redirect to User.vue component. Where some details will pre populated and those details i can able to edit and click on submit button, to update the array.

After successfully updating the array, Here comes the issue like, If i simply click on refresh button. Even the updated array also getting reset and set to the default value

I am not sure, How to keep the updated array (keep the same value) Even if page is refreshed also. Do I need to use any **vuex** or manage the updated array value in **localstorage** or How is the real-time scenario takes place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On each refresh your app is re-rendered and in `HelloWorld.vue` you get your data from local file, that's why you get the same array every time.

To render your updated array after refresh you will need to store the data in `localStorage` or in `sessionStorage` and if data exists there get that, if not use the data from local file.

State is not remembered on refresh that's why you need to store it somewhere.

If you're planning to use `vuex` you can save data after refresh with `vuex-persistedstate`. More info: [Vuex state on page refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43027499/vuex-state-on-page-refresh)

Comment: As mentioned, If i need to store the data in localStorage or in sessionStorage and if data exists there get that, if not use the data from local file.


Can you please give me example on my code.

Comment: Just have some idea like i need to use like localstorage.setItem(') and getItem. But i am not sure. If possible can u please edit the code https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-dhawan-3id77?file=/src/main.js

Comment: Here is edited code https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-violet-yv9df